# PHP Oauth2 server persist token in database

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I'm implementing a OAuth2 server with PHP (7.1) and [OAuth2-Server](https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/) library.

Having implemented and working everything I'm wondering if my design of the database table where I save the issued tokens is valid:

```
oauth_tokens
------------
token-id      # Token identifier
jwt           # (access_token)
```

Inspecting the process `OAuth2-Server` library is following to validate an access token is to only search for the token-id (which is not the access_token) in my database. So I'm currently giving no usage to the `oauth_tokens.jwt` field in my database.

However, in examples I found around internet everybody seems to save it, but I'm missing the purpose.